Weird 'mirroring sequences' during lifecycled events
One thing I've learned while building lifecycle management in reactive systems is that:

A) The event phases must come in pairs.
B) Each pair should be
composed of 2 sides, a "creating" side and a "destroying" side.
C) The destroying side op sequences must be an exact mirror of the
creating side.

Here is an example:
void onCreate() {
   objA.sub(this);
   objB.sub(this);
   objC.sub(this);
}

void onResume() {
   objD.sub(this);
   objE.sub(this);
}

void onPause() {
   objE.unsub(this);
   objD.unsub(this);
}

void onDestroy() {
   objC.unsub(this);
   objB.unsub(this);
   objA.unsub(this);
}

where:
enum Phase {
   alloc, create, resume, pause, destroy, dealloc
}

At first I came with this realization when building a sequential lifecycle manager... "easy".
The concept comes to such an extent... that additions and removals from observer collections MUST be traversed in reverse when dealing with "destroying" phases.
void dispatch(Phase phase) {
   if (phase.isAtMost(resume)) {
      for (i = 0, i < obs.length, i++) ... //dispatch phase
   } else {
      for (i = obs.length - 1, i >= 0, i--)... // dispatch phase
   }
}

The reason in this case is that 'on the fly' memory writes are the main culprit... not just during observer add/removals from arrays ([]) while event dispatches occur... (defending ourselves from null references during removals and "stunlocks" during additions)
but also, as I'll explain later, at the 'bare-metal' level during processor cache loads-stores.
This "mirroring" rule is so prevalent, that I recently revised a concurrent lifecycle manager... with just 2 phases ("activation" and "deactivation")... and the system was failing with a single hanged listener when many concurrent emissions (20^6) where being sent.
I remembered this rule and began looking in every point of the reactive branch in which 2 processes may be similar and I found a place inside "switchMap" where the sequences inside the activation process was similar in order to the ones inside the deactivation one.
The deactivation was sometimes occurring BEFORE the activation came to compute leaving an observer attached and NO way to find out where the error was.
So, I reviewed the steps inside the activation and created a logical sequence... finally I mirrored this exact same sequence during the deactivation process....
It worked to perfection.
At first this didn't made sense since observer addition and removals are being handled atomically with a CAS process (entire new instances)... so this means that somehow the way in which the Cache Acquiring Protocol handles arbitration is ALSO being benefited by this mirroring effect...
My other guess is that the way in which Threads are being enqueued by the platform(language) are making it a necessity to do this as a mirror sequence, even if what handles the process is a CAS process.
